# How to JSON.parse() json that contains nested json as a string on a property?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse the response from `aws secretsmanager`

The output looks like:

```
{
  "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:0000:secret:token-0000",
  "Name": "token",
  "VersionId": "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
  "SecretString": "{\"TOKEN\":\"000000000000\"}",
  "VersionStages": ["AWSCURRENT"],
  "CreatedDate": "0000"
}
```

When attempting to parse this string with `JSON.parse()`, it attempts to parse the string value in `SecretString` which has escaped quotes.

I would have expected to need to `JSON.parse` the response in two steps however this does not work.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN=$(node -e "\
  const result = JSON.parse('$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $ARN)'); \
  const token = JSON.parse(result.SecretString); \
  console.log(token); \
")

echo $TOKEN
```

How can I prevent the `JSON.parse` function from attempting to parse the string value of the `SecretString` - Alternatively, is there a better way to obtain the value?

Comment: The JavaScript code is correct, the issue is introduced by your shell script. Redirect the output of `aws secretsmanager` to a file then use Node.js to read and parse the content of the file. Or use `jq` instead of Node.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` does not attempt to parse JSON-encoded strings contained within the parsed object, so I don't think this is what's causing your problem. It's more likely to do with the shell's handling of the quotes.

I think a better way to do this would be to have your Node script call the `aws` CLI using [`child_process.execFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecfilefile-args-options-callback), rather than having the shell call `aws` and pass the result into Node.

If you need to access the `ARN` variable from Node you can do it using `process.env.ARN`.

Here's some code that should do the trick:

```js
async function main()
{
    const child_process = require('child_process');
    const util = require('util');
    const execFile = util.promisify(child_process.execFile);
    const json = (await execFile('aws', ['secretsmanager', 'get-secret-value', '--secret-id', process.env.ARN])).stdout;
    const result = JSON.parse(json);
    const token = result.SecretString;
    console.log(token);
}

main();
```

If you're going to be needing to do more of this kind of stuff, it might be worth looking at the [AWS SDK for NodeJS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html). Even with `execFile`, there are still some pitfalls with using CLI tools programmatically in this way, especially if you need to pass JSON *into* the CLI tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const json = {
  "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:0000:secret:token-0000",
  "Name": "token",
  "VersionId": "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
  "SecretString": "{\"TOKEN\":\"000000000000\"}",
  "VersionStages": ["AWSCURRENT"],
  "CreatedDate": "0000"
}

json.SecretString = JSON.parse(json.SecretString)

const { SecretString: { TOKEN: token } } = json

console.log('Token:', token)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with single quotes instead of double quotes for the string value of the JSON

```
 {
  "ARN": 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:0000:secret:token-0000',
  "Name": 'token',
  "VersionId": '0000-0000-0000-0000-0000',
  "SecretString": '{\"TOKEN\":\"000000000000\"}',
  "VersionStages": ['AWSCURRENT'],
  "CreatedDate": '0000'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code is correct, the issue is introduced by the shell script. You use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) (`$(...)`) to produce the JavaScript code. The output of the command contains `"` and `\`, the shell interprets them as quotes and escape characters and they do not reach the final string processed by the JavaScript code.

The easiest way to avoid this issue is to redirect the output of `aws` to a file then read the JSON the file using JavaScript:

```js
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $ARN) > /tmp/1.json
node -e "
  const result = require('/tmp/1.json');
  const secret = JSON.parse(result.SecretString);
  console.log(secret.TOKEN);
"
```

Or, even easier than that, install [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and run everything in a single command:

```bash
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $ARN) |
  jq -r '.SecretString | fromjson | .TOKEN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is malformed, should be:

```
const json = {
  "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:0000:secret:token-0000",
  "Name": "token",
  "VersionId": "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
  "SecretString": {"TOKEN":"000000000000"},
  "VersionStages": ["AWSCURRENT"],
  "CreatedDate": "0000"
}
```

Once fixed, you can access `TOKEN` like this:

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(json);
concole.log(parsed.SecretString.TOKEN);
```